# jQuery fadeOut is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and I'm trying to fade images out and in. Well, it's kinda weird, the image sometimes stays for much longer than expected, sometimes there's no fade, sometimes it only fades in.

````js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var interval;

      function startSlider() {
        console.log("Slider Started.");
        interval = setInterval(function () {
          $(".slides > li:first")
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo(".slides");
        }, 5000);
      }

      startSlider();
    </script>```
````

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `startSlider()` only once ? Because it seems OK, but having it running multiple times could explain weird behavior

Comment: nah man, i'm just calling it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help, I'm not sure what the issue is but I've messed with the code and now it works:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.image img:gt(0)').hide(); // to hide all except the first image when da page loads

  setInterval(function() {
    $('.image :first-child').fadeOut(1000)
      .next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('.image');
  }, 3000);
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
.image {
  position: relative;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2%;
}

.h {
  text-align: center;
}

.a {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>stuff</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="h">
    <h1 class="a">Automatic image transitions</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532009-6ba71e22f468?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620393470010-fd62b8ab841d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620406968602-f7e7cd9febce?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620415406067-68f6d8072fec?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxNnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620398399445-a5359701d43c?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyNXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620416530190-506ac680d67f?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyNnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620321268133-000441fd17aa?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw4OHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620399489382-8e77838306ff?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw4OXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" />
  </div>







  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that your internet is probably slowing down the execution of the code. If you switch to a different network, or run on a mobile connection, does the fade work as expected?

Comment: hmmm, when i change the network the transitions also becomes slower or faster. but not  consistent. my speed is more than 100 mbps.

Comment: Odd, I wonder if it has anything to do with CPU.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the sliding, you can put startSlider() inside jQuery document ready() event.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
      startSlider();
    });
```

here is a test:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
      console.log("Slider Started.");
      interval = setInterval(function () {
        $(".slides > li:first")
          .fadeOut(1000)
          .next()
          .fadeIn(1000)
          .end()
          .appendTo(".slides");
      }, 5000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      startSlider();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="slides">
    <li>item 1 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HHSuvHp.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></li>
    <li>item 2 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oKe8JBR.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```